# onClick not working on a button imported from 'react-select';

Tags: reactjs

when I click on the filter menu created by using react-select the function does not update the value of choice which is inside the state. In few words I need to set choice to 1 when I click the button imported from react-select

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import FetchRandomBet from "./fetchRandomBets";

const options = [
    { value: 1, label: 'less than 2' },
    { value: 2, label: 'more than 2' },
];

class Betslip extends Component {
    state = {
        names: [],
        odds: [],
        chioce: []
    };

    render() {
        function setChoice() {
            this.setState({ choice: 1 });
            console.log(this.state.choice);
        }
        return (
            <div className="betslip">

                <div className="betslip-top">
                    <h1 className="text">BETSLIP</h1>
                    <p className="text-two">BET WITH US!</p>
                    <Select
                        className="filter-menu"
                        options={options}
                        onClick={setChoice}
                    />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <FetchRandomBet value={options} />
                </div>

                <Button className="betnow" variant="contained">
                    Bet Now!
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Betslip;
```

Comment: I don't see you using `state.choice` anywhere.

Comment: You have a typo chioce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't immediately log the value of state after calling `setState` because it is asynchronous. I think you will find the state is updated, but your `console.log` runs too soon.

Use a callback to verify it has been set.

```
this.setState({ choice: 1 }, () => { console.log(this.state.choice) });
```

Side note: in your initial state values you have a typo in `chioce`.

Comment: can you help me in writing a good if else statement that shows the value when it is changed in the right time? thanks

Comment: render() {
        const { label } = options;
        const setLabel = label === 'less than 2' ? this.setState.choice = '1' : this.state.choice = '2';

        return (